# Kerberos authentication over HTTP failing with Ansible playbook

Tags: ansible, kerberos, windows-server-2012-r2, winrm

I am building a playbook in Ansible that will add some DNS entries to multiple Windows 2012 R2 domain controllers (DC). When attempting to authenticate over HTTP the DC rejects my credentials.

I have followed the documentation on the Ansible website to configure kerberos on my control machine.

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html#active-directory-support

I have also confirmed that I can log into the domain using my credentials:

```
$ klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
Default principal: my-user@<REDACTED>

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
10/06/2016 09:47:03  10/06/2016 19:47:03  krbtgt/<REDACTED>@<REDACTED>
    renew until 10/07/2016 09:46:59
10/06/2016 09:47:48  10/06/2016 19:47:03  HTTP/phx-dev-mwad01.<REDACTED>@<REDACTED>
    renew until 10/07/2016 09:46:59
10/06/2016 09:54:15  10/06/2016 19:47:03  HTTP/phx-dev-mwad02.<REDACTED>@<REDACTED>
    renew until 10/07/2016 09:46:59
10/06/2016 12:08:28  10/06/2016 19:47:03  HTTP/phx-dev-want01.<REDACTED>@<REDACTED>
    renew until 10/07/2016 09:46:59
```

I redacted the domain for security purposes.

Here is my config file for winrm:

```
ansible_user: my-user@<REDACTED>
ansible_password: SomePass
ansible_port: 5985
ansible_connection: winrm
# The following is necessary for Python 2.7.9+ when using default WinRM self-signed certificates:
ansible_winrm_server_cert_validation: ignore
```

I am able to connect to the windows servers over port 5986 (HTTPS), however in production the domain controllers are not configured for 5986 so Ansible **must** be able to establish the connection over port 5985 (HTTP). This requirement will not change in production.

When attempting the connection over 5985 my credentials are rejected;

```
fatal: [phx-dev-mwad02]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "kerberos: (u'http', u'Bad HTTP response returned from server. Code 500'), plaintext: the specified credentials were rejected by the server", "unreachable": true}
```

WinRM is set to allow remote management:

```
$winrm quickconfig
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.
```

Here is a gist to our WinRM configuration:

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f2baaff517287c535453dbba4ef03b69

And yes, I have confirmed that my credentials are correct.

Answer (score 5):

Look at `AllowUnencrypted = false` in your winrm server's config. It seems for now python winrm doesn't support [message encryption without https](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc251574.aspx). As workaround you can set it to true, which is **insecure**, so I strongly do not recommend this (cmd):

```
winrm set winrm/config/service @{AllowUnencrypted="true"}
```

See `HTTP or HTTPS endpoint` section of https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywinrm

Comment: While this will 'make it work' it will also leak production passwords in plaintext and is not recommended.

Comment: If kerberos is used, authentication passwords will not leak, but all other messages content (including third-party software passwords, registry keys and other private info) may leak and even be modified by mtm.